# Orient-db regex modifiers

Tags: sql, regex, orientdb

I'm working with orient-db database, and I've issues with regex pattern matching. I really need case-insensitive modifier to be present in the request, but somehow it doesn't work as I'm expecting.

Query:

```
select from UserAccounts where email MATCHES '^ther.*'
```

Returns as expected matches in lowercase.

Whenever I try to add a modifier, outside delimiters i.e.

```
select from UserAccounts where email MATCHES '\^ther.*\i'
```

I get an empty collection. Actually the query returns an empty collection whenever delimiters are present.

If there is no way to attach modifiers I could probably replace each 'alpha' char to an expression in square brackets i.e.

```
select from UserAccounts where email MATCHES "^[tT][hH][eE][rR].*"
```

But I'm not really happy with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Java case-insensitive regex modifier (from Pattern's special constructs) works in OrientDB 1.7.9 - for your example:

```
select from UserAccounts where email MATCHES '(?i)^ther.*'
```

(See also: [Pattern - Special Constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special))

I've added a comment to the corresponding OrientDB issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to specify modifiers for regex in *matches operator*.

For now the good solution would be to create [a custom function](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Functions), where you can use whole power of JS regexps.

But we definitely should add ability to specify modifiers in *MATCHES*, could you [create a feature request](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/new)?