# Does OrientDb support regular expressions?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm running OrientDb 2.2.6 using a plocal connection. I'm translating from one domain specific query language to OrientDb SQL. Since I need to translate a like command that allows regular expressions, I'd like to pass a regular expression similar to

```
[Ss]ay.*
```

but it looks like OrientDb 2.2 only supports the wild card '%'. Can Orient handle a regular expression like the one above? If not, do I need to create a custom function? Maybe there's an object in Orient's API that I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
Select from v where name MATCHES "<regex>"
```

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164411/orient-db-regex-modifiers)

[link2](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Where.html)